# How to use mix-blend-mode, but not have it affect child elements?

Tags: css, html, blending

Okay, so I'm building a WordPress site and the page in question can be seen here: http://test.pr-tech.com/power-line-markers/

The issue I am having is that I am using mix-blend-mode for one of my div containers to make use a 'lighten' blend on the background.

It works perfectly, but the issue I am having is that unfortunately the child elements inside the container (i.e. the text) are also inheriting the blend mode, and therefore it's making my text 'blend' as well, which isn't what I want (I want the text to have NO blend mode).

Anyways, you can see the code I am using below:

```
#category-intro-text {
    padding: 0.625em 0.938em;
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
    background-color: rgba(220, 235, 255, 0.8); repeat;
}
```

I tried applying something like 'mix-blend-mode: none;' to the text, but that doesn't work.

I've searched Google for an answer to this pretty extensively, but alas, there isn't much on this topic (if anything at all).

Answer (score 12):

I realise you asked this a while ago but I've been playing with the same issue today and managed to fix it like this.

Wrap the content inside the `#category-intro-text` div with another div that is positioned relatively. Ultimately, you'll want to add the style to your css and not inline as I've done here.

```
<div id="category-intro-text">
    <div style="position: relative;">   
        <h1>Power Line Markers</h1>
        Etc. Etc.
    </div>
</div>
```

Then remove the background colour and blending information you've got in the stylesheet for the `#category-intro-text` div. You should end up with...

```
#category-intro-text {
  padding: 0.625em 0.938em;
  position: relative;
}
```

Finally, use a `::before` pseudo element to add the blended layer.

```
#category-intro-text::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(220, 235, 255,0.8);
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

Hopefully that will do it. It is working perfectly for me with a multiply layer.

EDIT: [Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8y99rj4/) forked from the previous answer.

Comment: Its not working as blending mode , its just a transparency effect.

Answer (score 3):

Why use **mix-blend-mode** when there's **background-blend-mode**(maybe you have already tried that!) for that purpose. Actually mix-blend-modes blends the element it is applied on with everything beneath it. On the other hand background-blend-mode applied on a background blends only with the the background that is beneath it.

You can do this-

```
.outer-wrapper {
background: url(<url>), #fb3;
background-blend-mode: exclusion;
padding: 2em 4em;
}

.inner-text {
/**styling of you text***/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought I had it worked out with the `isolation` property, but no. I didn't have much luck researching a solution for this issue either.

I suppose you could use this old trick: http://jsfiddle.net/cwdtqma7/

HTML:

```
<div class="intro-wrap">
    <div class="intro-background"></div>
    <div class="intro-content">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>Welcome to the thing.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url('http://test.pr-tech.com/wp-content/themes/prtech/images/power-line-markers-bg.jpg') top left no-repeat;
    background-size: 800px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.intro-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.intro-background {
    background: url('http://test.pr-tech.com/wp-content/themes/prtech/images/category-intro-bg.png');
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
    padding: 32px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.intro-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, it would appear that that works, but it doesn't actually work. It seems like it's blending because the background image in use is a transparent .png file.

Comment: Oh, geez. I didn't notice it was transparent >.<

Comment: I changed it from a transparent background image to a RGBa color:

background-color: rgba(220, 235, 255, 0.8);... Still no luck though. Looks like this may be impossible  (at least as of the moment).

Answer (score 0):

> How to use mix-blend-mode, but not have it affect child elements?

Building upon @shanem's answer I found this solution

```js
function change(id){
  document.querySelector(id).style.backgroundColor="violet";
}
```

```css
.group{
  height:10rem;
  width:10rem;
  position:absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.group::before{
  content:"";
  visibility: visible;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:inherit;
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;
  z-index:-1;
}

.btn{
   background-color:red;
   color:white;
   visibility: visible;
   padding:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="g1" class="group" style="background-color:cyan;">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="change" onclick="change('#g1')"/>
</div>

<div id="g2" class="group" style="margin:1.5rem;background-color:yellow">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="change" onclick="change('#g2')"/>
</div>
```

The best part is that you can directly change the `background-color` using javascript.
The only caveat (if you'd want to call it that) is that every child element must set `visibility: visible;`